# Change textcolor between \cbstart and \cbend of package changebar

Tags: color, changebar

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage[xcolor,pdftex]{changebar}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\cbcolor{blue}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\cbstart
{\color{blue} % I want to remove this here and add a configuration to the preamble.
  \lipsum[2]
}
\cbend
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

I would like to automatically change the textcolor when I activate the changebar with `\cbstart` and switch back with `\cbend`.

Comment: It won't work, at least not for all variants. `\cbstart` can start in a different grouping level than `\cbend`. But you could redefine the `changebar` environment to add a color.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I see. I will try out to use a renewed `changebar` environment.

Answer (score 2):

My solution redefining the environment `changebar` as suggested by Ulrike Fischer:

```
\let\internchangebar\changebar
\let\endinternchangebar\endchangebar
\renewenvironment{changebar}
  {\begin{internchangebar}\bgroup\color{blue}}
  {\egroup\end{internchangebar}}
```